# Law of Large Numbers when expectation is infinite and random variable not identical

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, almost-everywhere

I am trying to prove the following question:

Let $X_i$ be sequence of indepedent non-negative random variables with $E(X_i) = \infty$ and $X_i$ having different distributions.

Is it true that
$$
\frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} \to \infty \ a.s.?
$$
I know that this is true when $X_i$ are i.i.d., but I have no idea how to proceed with $X_i$ having different distributions.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can even have $\frac {X_1+X_2+...+X_n} n \to 0$ almost surely!.

Let $(Y_n)$ be i.i.d non-negative with $EY_1=\infty$. Choose $a_n >0$ such that $P (\frac {Y_n} {a_n} >\frac  1 {2^{n}} )<\frac  1 {2^{n}}$. Use Borel Cantelli Lemma to conclude that $\frac {Y_n} {a_n} \to 0$ almost surely. Now put $X_n=\frac {Y_n} {a_n}$. Since $X_n \to 0$ almost surely it follows that the Cesaro  averages $\frac {X_1+X_2+...+X_n} n$ also $\to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused as to the introduction of $a_n$ here. Why not simply choose $X_n$ such that $P(X_n > 1/2^n) < 1/2^n$?

Comment: @davidolohowski Your inequality is satisfied by $X_n=0$ but then the condition $EX_n=\infty$ is not satisfied.